# What's the best way to get a podcast episode's shownotes using feedparser?

Tags: python, feedparser, podcast

I'd like to get the value that according to Apple's documentation goes in the `<itunes:summary` tag, but I'm finding it in different places for different podcasts.

Let's assume that `p` is the result of `feedparser.parse(url)`, I've found the shownotes in

```
p.entries[i].description
p.entries[i].content[0]
p.entries[i].content[1]
p.entries[i].summary
```

Is there a consistent way to get a podcast's show notes using feedparser? I'm assuming that feedparser is finding it in different places for different podcasts, but I think all of them at least put it in the itunes:summary tag. Is there a way to directly access that?